# Can't boot into Recovery via Wired Windows keyboard, can't log in to accounts either

Tags: keyboard, imac, recovery

I recently bought an iMac Mid 2011, and it has 3 accounts on it, all locked with passwords. I have an external Windows keyboard and external (wireless) mouse.

I don't know the passwords so I thought I'd try to boot into Recovery, which I couldn't do. It just kept starting into the system.

I tried different USB ports for the keyboard, I tried the far right and far left, I've tried literally every key combination, none of them work.

How the hell can I do this? I have a MacBook Pro but I'm not sure if you can turn it into a wired keyboard (sounds quite dumb).

Comment: To start in Recovery Mode you have press and hold Option-Command-R immediately after starting up your Mac, which key combination are you using with your Windows keyboard?

Comment: Alt + Windows Key + R

Comment: Oh I got in! Yay! I had to spam the keys and hold them and then spam them.

Comment: Great, I'm glad it worked. I'd be great if you could add an answer and mark it as accepted (you will not only help others but be able to collect the reputation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a delay before the keyboard starts, so when it shows you the white/gray screen, just hold Alt + Win Key + R for 2 seconds, then let go and instantly hold it again for 2 seconds.

Just keep doing that until it doesn't boot into the OS and then you know it's doing something.